# Fragment already active after coming back from picking camera intent

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have fragment A and it will call fragment B by click on button.

```
Fragment a = FragmentA
            .getInstance();

    // Supply index input as an argument.
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putBoolean(GlobalConstants.WANT_START_GAME, false);
    pokerOnlineProject.setArguments(args);

    FragmentTransaction transaction = getFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction();
    transaction.replace(R.id.poker_online_container, A,
            "A");
    transaction.addToBackStack(null);
    transaction.commit();
```

In this fragment B I call camera application in android OS with below code:

```
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,
            android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
```

startActivityForResult(i, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);

After that, I click back button, my application will return fragment A not in fragment B and I got exception "Fragment already active" when I tried to touch on button on fragment A.

Comment: I see you work with the Singleton-Design-Pattern. This is not recommended in combination with Fragments, because you hold an Instance of that Fragment independent from the Android Activity and Fragment-Lifecycle. Please try using the default Constructor.

Comment: FragmentA.getInstance(); does not necessarily mean that he use Singleton pattern. Maybe it is returning new instance of Fragment each time he call getInstance().

Answer (score -1):

Your photo is saved in **PATH_TO_SAVE** location.

You should in onActivityResult do something like this:

```
File file = new File(PATH_TO_SAVE);

Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file.getPath());
```